# SQLite: Calculate col based on the result of other Calculated Col

Tags: sql, sqlite

In a SQLite Database I have a table "test" containing an integer-typed col "a".

Based on that col, I want to calculate 2 more cols, but the second needs the result of the first.

So I tried the following:

```SQL
SELECT a, a+1 AS b, b*2 AS c FROM test
```

But in SQLite it does not work:

```
Error: no such column: b
```

In other DBMS is seems to work, I tried something similar at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_union) with the following Query.

```SQL
SELECT customerid as a, a+1 AS b, b*2 AS c FROM customers
```

... and there erevything is alright.

Is there a way to achive the same in SQLite without any Sub-Selects?

Comment: No.  You cannot use a column alias in an expression in the same `select` where it is defined.

Comment: So the only possible way is Subselecting?

Comment: Which is the other DBMS? (Just curious)

Comment: @GordonLinoff It seems to be the answer which OP was looking for. How about to turn it into an answer?

Comment: It seems as W3Schools uses Microsoft Jet database engine

Comment: I tried your second query on w3schools but got this error: __Error 1: could not prepare statement(1 no such column: a)__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html) where it talks about the limitations of column aliases in MySQL. Quoting a relevant line from the link:

> The WHERE clause determines which rows should be included in the GROUP BY clause, but it refers to the alias of a column value that is not known until after the rows have been selected, and grouped by the GROUP BY.

I guess, by extension, using the alias to select within the same query would fail for the same reason.

Instead, try using the column names in all the expressions. That way your code can work across all DBMS.

```
SELECT a, a+1 AS b, (a+1)*2 AS c FROM test
```

Comment: Your URL points to MySql documentation, while the OP's DBMS is SQLite. The various DBMS solve this in different ways. See as example Firebird, who can use the alias in the group by: http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-select.html

Comment: Besides that, the documentation portion you have selected talks about other issue: use the alias in the WHERE clause and not in the SELECT itself (which is the OP's need).

Comment: I realized that. But I can't find citation that discusses the exact issue the OP questions. This one comes close. Note the following words in my answer: _I guess, by extension..._

Comment: Yes, I need the Alias in the select itself, so there shouldn't be any Problem concerning WHERE. Copying the math from the one col to the other is in my mind not a great solution, because in the real Projekt there is some more math.

Comment: I tried your second query on w3schools but got this error: Error 1: could not prepare statement(1 no such column: a). So I don't know how you managed to make your query succeed. Can you confirm which DBMS successfully executed such a query?

Comment: retried it and it works. I used this site: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_union using the last SQL statement (with customerid) in the question

Comment: Retried and doesn't work on [w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_union](http://w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_union) . I agree that doing the math in every column is not the best solution. Your example on SO is a trivial addition and multiplication and might be far more complex in your actual environment. I can think of only one workaround. Storing the calculated value in another column and accessing that column directly.

Comment: googled and googled, but doubling the math seems to be the easiest solution - even if I dont really like it. Thanks for help!